# Error File ended while scanning use of \Gscale@box@dd

Tags: tables, texstudio

I am writting my Master thesis and I have some tables to include in my file but I am getting trouble with this part, I think that is the reason I got the error : File ended while scanning use of `\Gscale@box@dd`. I just wanted to have some lines in BOLD font but somehow it didn't work. This is my code:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
 \centering
 \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrrrr}
  \hline
 & \textbf{2009} & \textbf{2010} & \textbf{2011} & \textbf{2012} & 
 \textbf{2013} & \textbf{2014} & \textbf{2015} & \textbf{2016} & \textbf{2017} 
 & \textbf{2018} & \textbf{CAGR\_{5}} \\ 
  \hline
EBIT & 289 & 5.094 & 8.018 & 8.300 & 7.978 & 9.118 & 9.593 & 9.386 & 9.899 & 
9.121 & \textbf{0.01\%}\\ 
  EBIT*(1-T) = NOPLAT & 147 & 3.407 & 5.329 & 5.437 & 5.3860 & 6.092 & 6.652 & 
  6.711 & 8.044 & 6.728 & \textbf{2.01\%}\\ 
  Depreciation and Amortisation & 3.603 & 3.861 & 3.654 & 3.716 & 3.832 & 4.323 
  & 4.686 & 4.998 & 4.822 & 5.113 & \textbf{3.41\%}\\ 
\textbf{Gross cash flow} & \textbf{3.750} & \textbf{7.268} & \textbf{8.983} & 
\textbf{9.153} & \textbf{9.218} & \textbf{10.415} & \textbf{11.338} & 
\textbf{11.709} & \textbf{12.866} & \textbf{11.841} & \textbf{2.6\%}\\ 
  Changes in Working Capital & 1.802 & -403 & -1.615 & 1.755 & 986 & -551 & 
  -293 & -104 & 166 & -573 & \textbf{0.79\%}\\ 
  Capex & -3.302 & -3.208 & -3.626 & -5.194 & -6.671 & -6.063 & -5.851 & -5.813 
  & -7.082 & -7.649 & \textbf{4.76\%}\\ 
  \textbf{Free Cash Flows to Firm} & \textbf{2.250} & \textbf{3.657} & 
  \textbf{3.742} & \textbf{5.714} & \textbf{3.533} & \textbf{3.801} & 
  \textbf{5.194} & \textbf{5.792} & \textbf{5.950} & \textbf{3.619} & 
  \textbf{-0.97\%} \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}}

\end{table}
```

Thanks!

Comment: unrelated to the error but try to avoid doing `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%` scaling tables should only be a last resort measure, it makes inconsistent fonts and rule sizes, also note `\textbf{-0.97\%}` is a hyphen not a minus sign, it is best to use math mode for numeric quantities.

Comment: The thing is that the table is too large and I need it to fit in the text. Would you have any recommendation to make this happen?

Comment: you can use `\small` or `\footmotesize` (we have _lots_ of answers on site about making tables fit) if you use automatic scaling and it gets any smaller than that people won't be able to read it anyway so fitting the page is not the only consideration.

Comment: please post a complete small document that shows the problem. If I complete the fragment to an article class document using graphicx there is no error from resizebox but multiple errors from the `tabular`  `! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.`

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but you might be interested in the `booktabs` package for horizontal lines and the `siunitx` package for an improved alignment of numbers in table cells.

Comment: Thank you four your answers! I think there was a problem in {rrrrrrrrrrr}, which had only 11 spaces and there were 12 boxes in each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are three different versions of your table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%%%%% For table 2 %%%%%
\usepackage{tabularx}

%%%%% For table 2-3 %%%%%
\usepackage{booktabs}

%%%%% For table 3 %%%%%
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
 \centering
 \caption{Added the missing column specifier to make the table compilable. I do not recommend the use of resizebox to make a table fit into the text width.}
 \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrrrrr}
  \hline
 & \textbf{2009} & \textbf{2010} & \textbf{2011} & \textbf{2012} & 
 \textbf{2013} & \textbf{2014} & \textbf{2015} & \textbf{2016} & \textbf{2017} 
 & \textbf{2018} & \textbf{CAGR\_{5}} \\ 
  \hline
EBIT & 289 & 5.094 & 8.018 & 8.300 & 7.978 & 9.118 & 9.593 & 9.386 & 9.899 & 
9.121 & \textbf{0.01\%}\\ 
  EBIT*(1-T) = NOPLAT & 147 & 3.407 & 5.329 & 5.437 & 5.3860 & 6.092 & 6.652 & 
  6.711 & 8.044 & 6.728 & \textbf{2.01\%}\\ 
  Depreciation and Amortisation & 3.603 & 3.861 & 3.654 & 3.716 & 3.832 & 4.323 
  & 4.686 & 4.998 & 4.822 & 5.113 & \textbf{3.41\%}\\ 
\textbf{Gross cash flow} & \textbf{3.750} & \textbf{7.268} & \textbf{8.983} & 
\textbf{9.153} & \textbf{9.218} & \textbf{10.415} & \textbf{11.338} & 
\textbf{11.709} & \textbf{12.866} & \textbf{11.841} & \textbf{2.6\%}\\ 
  Changes in Working Capital & 1.802 & -403 & -1.615 & 1.755 & 986 & -551 & 
  -293 & -104 & 166 & -573 & \textbf{0.79\%}\\ 
  Capex & -3.302 & -3.208 & -3.626 & -5.194 & -6.671 & -6.063 & -5.851 & -5.813 
  & -7.082 & -7.649 & \textbf{4.76\%}\\ 
  \textbf{Free Cash Flows to Firm} & \textbf{2.250} & \textbf{3.657} & 
  \textbf{3.742} & \textbf{5.714} & \textbf{3.533} & \textbf{3.801} & 
  \textbf{5.194} & \textbf{5.792} & \textbf{5.950} & \textbf{3.619} & 
  \textbf{-0.97\%} \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\footnotesize \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\caption{With the use of tabularx  to introduce automatic linebreaks in the first column. I have also replaced the hlines by rules from the booktabs package and decreased the horizontal wite space between columns as well as the font size. Lastly, I have used math mode for minus signs.}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xrrrrrrrrrrr}
  \toprule
 & \textbf{2009} & \textbf{2010} & \textbf{2011} & \textbf{2012} & 
 \textbf{2013} & \textbf{2014} & \textbf{2015} & \textbf{2016} & \textbf{2017} 
 & \textbf{2018} & \textbf{CAGR\_{5}} \\ 
  \midrule
EBIT & 289 & 5.094 & 8.018 & 8.300 & 7.978 & 9.118 & 9.593 & 9.386 & 9.899 & 
9.121 & \textbf{0.01\%}\\ 
  EBIT*(1-T) = NOPLAT & 147 & 3.407 & 5.329 & 5.437 & 5.3860 & 6.092 & 6.652 & 
  6.711 & 8.044 & 6.728 & \textbf{2.01\%}\\ 
  Depreciation and Amortisation & 3.603 & 3.861 & 3.654 & 3.716 & 3.832 & 4.323 
  & 4.686 & 4.998 & 4.822 & 5.113 & \textbf{3.41\%}\\ 
\textbf{Gross cash flow} & \textbf{3.750} & \textbf{7.268} & \textbf{8.983} & 
\textbf{9.153} & \textbf{9.218} & \textbf{10.415} & \textbf{11.338} & 
\textbf{11.709} & \textbf{12.866} & \textbf{11.841} & \textbf{2.6\%}\\ 
  Changes in Working Capital & 1.802 & $-403$ & $-1.615$ & 1.755 & 986 & $-551$ & 
  $-293$ & $-104$ & 166 & $-573$ & \textbf{0.79\%}\\ 
  Capex & $-3.302$ & $-3.208$ & $-3.626$ & $-5.194$ & $-6.671$ & $-6.063$ & $-5.851$ & $-5.813$ 
  & $-7.082$ & $-7.649$ & \textbf{4.76\%}\\ 
  \textbf{Free Cash Flows to Firm} & \textbf{2.250} & \textbf{3.657} & 
  \textbf{3.742} & \textbf{5.714} & \textbf{3.533} & \textbf{3.801} & 
  \textbf{5.194} & \textbf{5.792} & \textbf{5.950} & \textbf{3.619} & 
  \textbf{-0.97\%} \\ 
   \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table} 
\small 
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\caption{On a landscape page the table fits perfectly fine into the textwidth even without adding linebreaks in the first column if one slightly reduces the font size and the tabcolsep.}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lrrrrrrrrrrr}
  \toprule
 & \textbf{2009} & \textbf{2010} & \textbf{2011} & \textbf{2012} & 
 \textbf{2013} & \textbf{2014} & \textbf{2015} & \textbf{2016} & \textbf{2017} 
 & \textbf{2018} & \textbf{CAGR\_{5}} \\ 
  \midrule
EBIT & 289 & 5.094 & 8.018 & 8.300 & 7.978 & 9.118 & 9.593 & 9.386 & 9.899 & 
9.121 & \textbf{0.01\%}\\ 
  EBIT*(1-T) = NOPLAT & 147 & 3.407 & 5.329 & 5.437 & 5.3860 & 6.092 & 6.652 & 
  6.711 & 8.044 & 6.728 & \textbf{2.01\%}\\ 
  Depreciation and Amortisation & 3.603 & 3.861 & 3.654 & 3.716 & 3.832 & 4.323 
  & 4.686 & 4.998 & 4.822 & 5.113 & \textbf{3.41\%}\\ 
\textbf{Gross cash flow} & \textbf{3.750} & \textbf{7.268} & \textbf{8.983} & 
\textbf{9.153} & \textbf{9.218} & \textbf{10.415} & \textbf{11.338} & 
\textbf{11.709} & \textbf{12.866} & \textbf{11.841} & \textbf{2.6\%}\\ 
  Changes in Working Capital & 1.802 & $-403$ & $-1.615$ & 1.755 & 986 & $-551$ & 
  $-293$ & $-104$ & 166 & $-573$ & \textbf{0.79\%}\\ 
  Capex & $-3.302$ & $-3.208$ & $-3.626$ & $-5.194$ & $-6.671$ & $-6.063$ & $-5.851$ & $-5.813$ 
  & $-7.082$ & $-7.649$ & \textbf{4.76\%}\\ 
  \textbf{Free Cash Flows to Firm} & \textbf{2.250} & \textbf{3.657} & 
  \textbf{3.742} & \textbf{5.714} & \textbf{3.533} & \textbf{3.801} & 
  \textbf{5.194} & \textbf{5.792} & \textbf{5.950} & \textbf{3.619} & 
  \textbf{-0.97\%} \\ 
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```